# remote: error: Internal server error - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, version-control

When trying to push to a repo from one machine we get this error. When run from another machine with the same config, there is no error.

```
[shadow@shadow UserPromote]$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 802 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: Internal server error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://codehub.xyz.com/scm/git/ARCH/ruby/UserPromote'
[shadow@shadow UserPromote]$
```

This is the Git Config:

```
[shadow@shadow UserPromote]$ git config --list
user.email=shrdev@xyz.com
user.name=Architecture Team: shadow
color.ui=auto
http.sslverify=false
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=http://codehub.xyz.com/scm/git/ARCH/ruby/UserPromote
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
[shadow@shadow UserPromote]$
```

[EDIT]

This is the config of the working machine:

```
[peanut@peanut UserPromote]$ git config --list
user.email=shrdev@xyz.com
user.name=Architecture Team
color.ui=auto
http.sslverify=false
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=http://codehub.xyz.com/scm/git/ARCH/ruby/UserPromote
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=844x391+30+58 189 177
[peanut@peanut UserPromote]$
```

I am still new to Admining this, any assistance, or even a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. In my research on this site I have found many similar issues, but they all seem to have more specific errors.

-Shawn

Comment: are you sure config is identical between the working and non-working machine? I think it should be https url, not http.

Comment: I updated the post with a paste of the working machine config.

Comment: any difference in what you're trying to push?

Comment: nope, same content. =/